# Does a status transition from an issue status to the same status make sense in Redmine

Tags: workflow, redmine

In Redmine you can define/update issue workflows in a status-matrix based way: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineIssueTrackingSetup#Workflow

While generating workflow graphs out of our Redmine database, I encountered some status transitions that were set between identical status, e.g. `Resolved`-> `Resolved`.

On first sight this makes no sense to me, but it is allowed by Redmine. So I'd like to ask if there are any reasonable considerations to do this OR can there be any side effects if I remove those status transitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test confirms that those status transitions are *not* necessary: Updating an issue without modifying the status is not considered to be a status transition.

Comment: I did a test myself, but I'm afraid that I miss something important what I can not see. Any hints why these transitions are allowed ?

Answer (score 0):

These transitions are just there because of the basic matrix structure. If you inspect the default workflow matrices (I don't know if there are some online demo databases but you could always start a 30 day easyredmine trial and see them there yourself) you would see that the cross status boxes are always "unselected" (hence the logic demands it).

Answer (score 0):

1.The status `Resolved-> Resolved` is important because at times dynamic status change may or may not happen depending on the user's requirement.

2.Also understanding the workflow engine as an open source developer with the right context irrespective of which language one narrates to make it understand is also the right perspective to look at it. The workflow matrix wouldn't make any sense if there is **NO** checkbox to refine the workflow. It would mean there is no element of logic present at that place.